Flutter easy_localization won't work with Android Studio Ladybug build environment
I upgraded an existing Flutter project to Ladybug and build started failing. I created a new Ladybug project from scratch and started adding Flutter dependencies to pubspec.yaml until I got the failure. That failure occurred when I added easy_localization: ^3.0.3. I bumped easy_localization to the latest version 3.0.7, but get the same failure:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\kevin\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\kevin\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

Ladybug is pretty new, so I assume the developer will update easy_localization soon - everything worked fine with Koala. easy_localization is tightly integrated with my project, so rewriting all tht code is out of the question. Is the best answer to downgrade back to Koala or is there a way to downgrade elements of Ladybug (jdk, gradle) to make it work?
Thanks in advance!

Ladybug has a lot of bugs. Downgrade to koala to make it work unless they fix ladybug.

Yes, that's what I did and everything works great now. Thanks!
